# How much work should we delegate to Mongo and not java?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have an application that fetches data from MongoDB based on IDs. What I am doing and encouraging my team to do is that Mongo should retrieve the response that the java API has to return so we just use java to map the Mongo response into a pojo. Is this the correct approach?. Should we delegate to Mongo as much processing as we can to avoid using java programming to create responses based on data from the MongoDB?

Comment: Your current approach is pretty standard, and from the Java POJO your application would then serialize the POJO into a JSON string to return to the caller.  Include more details if you really need a formal answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Quite subjective, it depends, but here is the thought-process

API interface and database should be always be decoupled. Any change expected in the API signature should not result in DB changes every time, and vice versa.

Your database query result can match to the domain entity in your code, and have a mapper to map the fields as expected in the API. That way, your domain logic changes less frequently (and less bugs)

Though, if performance is the main consideration, then it makes sense to map and fetch only required values by the API.

Problem with Spring-boot is the default layered architecture. Though it works fine for smaller applications, everything gets implemented with Data source in the center. Hence, the design becomes data driven instead of domain-driven. I suggest you start looking into DDD and hexagonal architecture.